# Replacing "*" in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of values.

```
mydf.head():

    Amount Date        Description

0   39.95  2017-03-30  Paypal *A2zkidsltd     
1    2.39  2017-04-01  Mcdonalds              
2    8.03  2017-04-01  Wm Morrison
3   34.31  2017-04-01  Wm Morrison
4   10.56  2017-04-03  Asda Superstore
```

I wish to replace all "*" with nothing. I use the pandas replace function on the Description column.

```
mydf['Description'].replace('*','', inplace=True)
```

And look again at the result:

```
mydf.head()

0   39.95 2017-03-30  Paypal *A2zkidsltd     
1    2.39 2017-04-01  Mcdonalds              
2    8.03 2017-04-01  Wm Morrison
3   34.31 2017-04-01  Wm Morrison
4   10.56 2017-04-03  Asda Superstore
```

The first transaction still contains a "*".

This is seen for all transactions containing "*".

I have looked at the documentation;

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

However I do not see where I am going wrong. What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: I think you need `str`  you can try: `df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace('*','')`

Comment: The reason it does not work as expected is because `pandas.DataFrame.replace` matches the entire string value to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace('*','')
```

There does not seem to be option for `inplace` so, need to assign to `column` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping it - `*` is a special character :)

```
mydf['Description'].replace('\*','', inplace=True)
```

Or as Sacul suggests:

```
mydf['Description'].replace('*','', regex=False, inplace=True)
```